# How to create single selection list in a window with AS400 DDS?

Tags: ibm-midrange

Actually I am not asking for details about the implementation. I know how to implement single selection list with subfile in a whole screen, but when I tried to apply the same principle to  a window things did not quite go as expected. Here is the DDS for the window and the subfile:

```
A        R SWCCHK03                      SFL
A          S0AVAL        1Y  0H          SFLCHCCTL
A          S0OPTN       10A   O     
A        R SWCCHK04                      SFLCTL(SWCCHK03)
A                                        OVERLAY
A                                        SFLDSP
A                                        SFLDSPCTL
A 30                                     SFLCLR
A 31                                     SFLEND
A                                        SFLSIZ(0006)
A                                        SFLPAG(0005)
A                                        WINDOW(*DFT 13 32)
A                                        SFLSNGCHC(*RSTCSR *AUTOSLT)
A                                     1 3'Option'
```

And here is the loop in the RPGLE for displaying and processing the selected option:

```
C      SR300      BEGSR
C      *IN12      DOWEQ      *OFF
C                 EXFMT      SWCCHK04
C      *IN12      IFEQ       *OFF
C                 GOTO       SR300E
C                 ENDIF
C                 READC      SWCCHK03
C      S0AVAL     IFEQ       4
C                 ITER
C                 ENDIF
                  .
                  .
                  .
C                 ENDDO
C      SR300E     ENDSR
```

Under certain circumstances I want to set S0AVAIL to 4 so that some options in the single selection list will become unavailable, and if a user tries to select such an option the window and the single selection list would remain on the screen and the cursor located on the first option until the user chooses either to quit the window or select an available option.

This implementation has no problem if a user selects an available option. But if the user selects an unavailable option, the window would remain on the screen as required, but the cursor will move to the top left corner of the window rather than remaining at the first option in the selection list. And even if I can move the cursor back to the option manually, it will go to the window corner again next time when an unavailable option is selected. How did this happen? And how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How does this code compile?  There is a 50 column subfile field (S0OPTN) in a 32 column wide window.  Make sure you are running the code you think you should be.

When I try similar code, I am *unable to select* the rows with S0AVAL=4.  How are you able to 'select' an unavailable choice?  If I use the cursor keys, the cursor jumps over the unavailable selection.  If I click with the mouse, I get an 'input inhibited' keyboard error.  What terminal emulator are you using?  I am using Personal Communications 6.0 for Windows.

Working code follows:

```
 A*
 A          R SWCCHK03                  SFL
 A            S0AVAL         1Y 0H      SFLCHCCTL
 A            S0OPTN        10A  O  6 11
 A*
 A          R SWCCHK04
 A                                      SFLCTL(SWCCHK03)
 A                                      OVERLAY
 A  27                                  SFLDSP
 A N28                                  SFLDSPCTL
 A  28                                  SFLCLR
 A  29                                  SFLEND
 A                                      SFLSIZ(06)
 A                                      SFLPAG(05)
 A                                      CF12(12)
 A                                      WINDOW(*DFT 13 32)
 A                                      SFLSNGCHC(*RSTCSR *AUTOSLT)
 A            SFLRRN         4S 0H      SFLRCDNBR(CURSOR)
 A                                  1 10'Title'
 A            CHOICE         4S 0   3  1
 A                                  4  5'Choose one'                               

 h/copy qrpglesrc,stdhspec
 h* dbgview(*list)

 fsotest    cf   e             workstn
 f                                     SFILE(SWCCHK03:RRN)

 c* clear sfl
 c                   z-add     1             sflrrn
 c                   setoff                                       272829
 c                   seton                                        28
 c                   write     SWCCHK04
 c                   setoff                                       28
 c* load sfl
 c     1             do        9             rrn               4 0
 c                   movel     rrn           s0optn
 c                   if        rrn = 4
 c                   z-add     4             s0aval
 c                   else
 c                   z-add     0             s0aval
 c                   endif
 c                   write     SWCCHK03
 c                   seton                                        27
 c                   enddo

 C     *IN12         DOWEQ     *OFF
 C                   EXFMT     SWCCHK04

 C     *IN12         IFEQ      *ON
 C                   LEAVE
 C                   ENDIF

 C                   READC     SWCCHK03                               80
 C  n80              do
 C                   movel     rrn           choice
 C                   z-add     0             S0aval
 C                   update    SWCCHK03
 C                   enddo
 C                   ENDDO

 c                   seton                                        lr
```

Comment: Sorry, S0OPTN should be 10 characters long. I mixed it up with another field. Regarding selecting an unavailable option,somehow I had no problem placing the cursor to it. I am using Personal Communications 5.8 for Windows.